# Use select list value to return json

Tags: jquery, json

I have a select list:

```
<select name="Country" id="Country">
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
</select>
```

And some json

```
[
    {
        "selection":"US",
        "foo": "lorem"
    },
    {
        "selection":"US",
        "foo": "lorem lorem"
    },
    {
        "selection":"DE",
        "foo": "ipsum"
    },
    {
        "selection":"DE",
        "foo": "ipsum ipsum" 
    }
]
```

I want to return all of the content that's "selection" object matches the value from the select list.

```
function load_Content() {
    $.getJSON('./path/to.json', function(data) {
        //this works, it gets the value from the select
        var filter = $('#ForexCountry').val();
        var myData = JSON.parse(//need to parse json into string?);
        var countryData = $.grep(myData.filter, function (element, 
        index) {
            return element.category == filter;
        });
    });
}
```

I can't seem to get this in the right format. I need to:

1. Get the country code from the drop down and store it as "filter"
2. Get the json, filter it to only return the object's whose "selection" is the same as the "filter" value
3. Return the data

Comment: `$.getJSON()` auto parses the data before giving it to the method.  You don't have to parse it, and in fact will get an error if you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter` here. It will return all the results based on condition in the callback. Also you do not need to parse the response to JSON as it will already be a JSON.

```
var filter = $('#ForexCountry').val();
var countryData = data.filter(el => el.selection === filter);
```

Comment: which is better, grep or filter? I know you cannot chain grep

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the grep method it's something like

```
function load_Content() {
    $.getJSON('./path/to.json', function(data) {
        var filter = $('#ForexCountry').val();
        var matchingElements = $.grep(data, function(element){
            return element.selection === filter;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: which is better, grep or filter? I know you cannot chain grep

Comment: If possible, filter is better as it is native.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be filtering

Comment: Was too quick, I fixed it and have it working. I went with fitler over grep